# How to Delete Python Files which have Similar Name?

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

Hello I have Different CSV files but some of them have similar names in the middle. 
File names:
  1. ab.New_Groups.3123.csv
  2. bca.New_Groups.2134.csv
  3. asdad.DDog.213.csv
  4. asda.Cat.12312.csv

This is whatI have so far:

```
import glob
import zipfile
import os
#will unzip the file into a folder
with zipfile.ZipFile("October.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
     zip_ref.extractall(("/path/Reports"))
#deleting files which are not useful
extension = ".csv"

#going to the directory where the files at
os.chdir("path/Reports")
all_filenames = [f for f  in glob.glob('[New_Groups]*{}'.format(extension))]

#for d in all_filenames:
os.remove(d)
print all_filenames
```

It does not delete anything, and my goal is deleting all the files which have "New_Groups" on the name.

thank you in advance!

Comment: `os.remove(d)` should delete file `d`, but in `all_filenames` you have the original list of files retrieved when the file existed. Check with the windows folder browser if the file really still exists.

Comment: Deleting files with python? Why not simply `ls | grep New_Groups | xargs rm` ?

Comment: In my script i have it as #comment its not actual part of it. @Aryerez

Comment: @meissner_  It is part of a big script, and I am trying to keep everything in python, might call a bash script it is a good idea thank you!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @meissner_

The solution was:
    #going to the directory where the files at
    os.chdir("path/Reports")

```
#this will delete all the files which contains New_Groups
os.system("ls | grep New_Groups | xargs rm")
```

Comment: This will also delete files named `abdc.New_Groups.txt` as well as a file named `New_groups.py` or anything else. To ensure you only delete the files with extension `.csv` you should amend your `glob.glob()` statement as I mention above. Your current statement will also print anything with the characters included within the `[]` and not necessarily in that order. For example, it will find files titled `N.csv` as well as `soup.csv`, etc.

Comment: I unzip a file so I only which contains only csv files but I understand your point! I tried the new version of yours and [] that seemed to be the problem. @currand60

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `*` to wildcard the beginning of the filename:

```
In [13]: [f for f  in glob.glob('[New_Groups]*{}'.format(extension))]
Out[13]: []

In [14]: [f for f  in glob.glob('*New_Groups*{}'.format(extension))]
Out[14]:
['2.ab.New_Groups.3123.csv',
 '1.ab.New_Groups.3123.csv',
 'ab.New_Groups.3123.csv']
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that, and it returns me all the files

Comment: Woops! I pasted in the wrong line. Should be fixed now. The above will return only files that match a pattern like ^.*New_Groups.*csv$. The `[]` works like character range in a regex.